# Why level set to 1000 'calculateLevel' problem

Tags: javascript

my problem is that with the function 'calculateLevel' the level jumps to 1000 from the XP content 54592352.

```
const calculateLevel = (xp) => {
    let next = 500;
    let level = 0;
    for (let i = 1; next <= xp && level < 1000; i++) {
        next += parseInt(next * (0.235) * (1.00 - (0.0095 * level)));
        level++;
    }
    return {level, next};
};
```

```
console.log(calculateLevel(54592351)); // Output { level: 106, next: 54592352 }
console.log(calculateLevel(54592352)); // Output { level: 1000, next: 0 }
```

I guess the problem lies in the calculation of the level.

```
next += parseInt(next * (0.235) * (1.00 - (0.0095 * level)));
```

Comment: `parseInt` expects a string, not a number. Are you just trying to round? But what do you expect your calculation to return? There's no way to help unless you explain the translation of `xp` to `level`.

Comment: use `Math.floor` replace `parseInt`